# HP PhotoSmart C4400 printer always says "paper out" and doesn't attempt to feed paper, even if paper is loaded

Tags: windows-7, printer, hp-photosmart

I have a HP C4400 printer and it claims to be out of paper (which is not true) and don't even try to pull the paper.

I have already followed these instructions with no success: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00786157&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=3418705

Two strange things:

1. I used the printer successfully minutes before this problem.
2. It prints its test page successfully (by pressing the cancel and color buttons simultaneously).

How can I fix this problem?

PS: Sorry about the creepy english.

Comment: See if [this thread](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Printing-Questions/c4400-c4480-false-paper-jam-fix/td-p/207891) helps.

Comment: Tried reinstalling the printer? Tried with different OS(say XP)? Tried with different machine?

Comment: @harrymc: please post it as answer because it is a possible answer..

Comment: @tumchaaditya: Done. I hope this helps.

Comment: @tumchaaditya your solution worked (to try in another os/machine). if you want to get the bounty, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take these steps:

1. Try reinstalling the printer(drivers).
2. Try the printer on a different OS on the same machine(if you have any).
3. Try the printer on a different machine

If it is working fine on a different machine(as you say), the problem is with your PC.
In that case,

1. Run sfc /scannow from administrator command prompt
2. Try a different USB port(loose contact/bad port etc.)
3. Try reinstalling the printer.
4. Try using windows 7 default printer driver instead of drivers on the printer CD in case you are using them or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

It you have tried all of the above, checking the drivers, turn on off etc, try unplugging it from the USB port it is in, and try it in another port. WHen you plug it in it should recognize the printer and say it is installing the drivers. Once it has done this go to devices and printers, and if it not there click add printer, and go through the steps. Once you have found it, and added it as a printer, it should give you the option to print a test page. If it doesn't right click the printer icon and go to printer properties. Within this somewhere there is an option that says print test page.

This worked for me and i hope it helps a few people out. I have no idea why it did this as mine was working absolutely fine aswell but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

The thread [c4400 c4480 false paper jam fix](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Printing-Questions/c4400-c4480-false-paper-jam-fix/td-p/207891) has some more procedures in addition to the ones mentioned in your link :

> ... Opened rear access door. Wiped rollers with damp paper towel.
>
> ... it was the clear plastic wheel that just seem to be stuck and not
>   rotating with the main printer shaft. A gentle push back on to the
>   shaft and working as normal.
>
> ... I found a reference to the clear plastic wheel coming loose that
>   controls the operation. I removed the left side cover and found the
>   wheel.  In my case mine was attached fine.  I did use a dust-off
>   compressed air to spray between the optical sensor and the clear
>   plastic wheel. 
>  Hah! that has fixed it! Apparently dust can
>   collect in the slot of the sensor. While it does take a Torx T-10 to
>   get to, this is not a difficult fix.

Comment: harrymc thank you for your answer. but unfortunately none of these procedures worked for me. i've managed to get it working with @tumchaaditya's comment.

Comment: Hmmm, this means that this is a software problem, not hardware. Do I understand correctly that you have given up on making it work on one computer and will be using it on another?

Comment: No, I want it to work on both computers.

Comment: But after testing in the second computer, I got no time to try again on the first computer. When I get home I'll try again.

Comment: If the printer doesn't work on the first computer, then there is a problem, maybe with the driver. The [driver found on HP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=3655561&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=3655558) is old and dates from 2009. Things you might do : (1) first see if there is a driver update waiting in the Windows Update optional section (2) if not, it might be better to delete the printer and reboot so to let Windows redetect it.

Answer (score 1):

If using windows From Start go to

Control panel:

Administrator tools:

Services:

Print spooler:

Right click and stop spooler.

Turn printer power off and after a minute back on.

Right click on print spooler and restart it.

This frequently solves the no paper error

Answer (score 0):

On the computer physically connected to the printer, go to Start > services.msc > Printer Spooler > restart. Please spread this fix! I don't know why this isn't easily googlable after soooooo many years of dealing with problem. It's the same fix for when a print job won't cancel and the print queue continuously says "Deleting"